# Yibbum with an incompetent woman

Tags: halacha, women, yibbum-chalitza-levirate, handicap-disabled-impair, even-haezer

According to Halacha, are Jewish men  obligated to do Yibbum with their widowed sister in law if she is mentally incompetent (the equivalent of a deaf mute)? Or no, since she is not competent to consent to the marriage is it invalid from the get go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chalitza requires mental competence to be effective whilst Yibbum does not. Accordingly, a mentally incompetent woman could establish a legal marriage to the brother without consent. Whether that's wise or not is a question particular to the given situation, but note she can't marry anyone else before dealing with the residual relationship with the brother. (Shulchan Arukh EH 172:12-16)